# SSIS - Batch load Hive table through ODBC

Tags: ssis, hive, odbc

I am attempting to port an SSIS package to target HIVE instead of DB2. I am having an issue with the ODBC Destination task using the Hortonworks HIVE ODBC. I previously tried the Microsoft ODBC but that failed to create a valid insert query.

I read the documentation "Leveraging a Hadoop cluster from SQL Server Integration Services" which mentioned that writing to Hive from ODBC is not possible but this documentation is from 2013.

The problem:
I have a data flow task with an OLE DB Source(DB2) and a ODBC Destination(Hive). If I set the ODBC Destination to 'Row-by-row' then the load completes as expected. However, if I set it to 'Batch' then I only receive the following error:

Error: 0x384 at Push Tokens to HIVE, ODBC Destination [2]: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. SQLExecute returned error while inserting row 1

I have attached the ODBC trace from the problematic task. I expected to see a SQLExecute SQL_ERROR in the trace but that seems to be missing.

Is this even possible through ODBC or do I need to use HDFS Destination followed by a Hive Task?

```
DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   ENTER SQLPrepareW 
        HSTMT               0x08D45108
        WCHAR *             0x0583CEE4 [      86] "INSERT INTO `default`.`temp_000000000000_return` ( `link_id`,`tok_data`) VALUES (?, ?)"
        SDWORD                    86

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   EXIT  SQLPrepareW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x08D45108
        WCHAR *             0x0583CEE4 [      86] "INSERT INTO `default`.`temp_000000000000_return` ( `link_id`,`tok_data`) VALUES (?, ?)"
        SDWORD                    86

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   ENTER SQLSetStmtAttrW 
        SQLHSTMT            0x08D45108
        SQLINTEGER                  21 <SQL_ATTR_PARAMS_PROCESSED_PTR>
        SQLPOINTER          0x057D8578
        SQLINTEGER                   0 

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   EXIT  SQLSetStmtAttrW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHSTMT            0x08D45108
        SQLINTEGER                  21 <SQL_ATTR_PARAMS_PROCESSED_PTR>
        SQLPOINTER          0x057D8578
        SQLINTEGER                   0 

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   ENTER SQLSetStmtAttrW 
        SQLHSTMT            0x08D45108
        SQLINTEGER                  20 <SQL_ATTR_PARAM_STATUS_PTR>
        SQLPOINTER          0x084B4158
        SQLINTEGER                   0 

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   EXIT  SQLSetStmtAttrW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHSTMT            0x08D45108
        SQLINTEGER                  20 <SQL_ATTR_PARAM_STATUS_PTR>
        SQLPOINTER          0x084B4158
        SQLINTEGER                   0 

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   ENTER SQLBindParameter 
        HSTMT               0x08D45108
        UWORD                        1 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_PARAM_INPUT>
        SWORD                      -16 <SQL_C_SLONG>
        SWORD                        4 <SQL_INTEGER>
        SQLULEN                   10
        SWORD                        0 
        PTR                0x08316178
        SQLLEN                     4
        SQLLEN *            0x08315F98

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   EXIT  SQLBindParameter  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x08D45108
        UWORD                        1 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_PARAM_INPUT>
        SWORD                      -16 <SQL_C_SLONG>
        SWORD                        4 <SQL_INTEGER>
        SQLULEN                   10
        SWORD                        0 
        PTR                0x08316178
        SQLLEN                     4
        SQLLEN *            0x08315F98 (137452312)

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   ENTER SQLBindParameter 
        HSTMT               0x08D45108
        UWORD                        2 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_PARAM_INPUT>
        SWORD                       -8 <SQL_C_WCHAR>
        SWORD                       -8 <SQL_WCHAR>
        SQLULEN                   35
        SWORD                        0 
        PTR                0x057F85C8
        SQLLEN                    72
        SQLLEN *            0x08315FB8

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   EXIT  SQLBindParameter  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x08D45108
        UWORD                        2 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_PARAM_INPUT>
        SWORD                       -8 <SQL_C_WCHAR>
        SWORD                       -8 <SQL_WCHAR>
        SQLULEN                   35
        SWORD                        0 
        PTR                0x057F85C8
        SQLLEN                    72
        SQLLEN *            0x08315FB8 (137452312)

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2c5c   ENTER SQLExecute 
        HSTMT               0x08D45108

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2c5c   EXIT  SQLExecute  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x08D45108

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2c5c   ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 <SQL_HANDLE_STMT>
        SQLHANDLE           0x08D45108
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0927EFA0
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0927D784
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0927DF98 
        SQLSMALLINT               1024 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0927D788

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2c5c   EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 <SQL_HANDLE_STMT>
        SQLHANDLE           0x08D45108
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0927EFA0
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0927D784
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0927DF98 
        SQLSMALLINT               1024 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0927D788

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   ENTER SQLFreeHandle 
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 <SQL_HANDLE_STMT>
        SQLHANDLE           0x08D45108

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   EXIT  SQLFreeHandle  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 <SQL_HANDLE_STMT>
        SQLHANDLE           0x08D45108

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   ENTER SQLDisconnect 
        HDBC                0x0254EBD8

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   EXIT  SQLDisconnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HDBC                0x0254EBD8

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   ENTER SQLFreeHandle 
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x0254EBD8

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   EXIT  SQLFreeHandle  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x0254EBD8

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   ENTER SQLFreeHandle 
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 <SQL_HANDLE_ENV>
        SQLHANDLE           0x0254E748

DtsDebugHost    1e9c-2488   EXIT  SQLFreeHandle  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 <SQL_HANDLE_ENV>
        SQLHANDLE           0x0254E748
```

Comment: What versions of BIDS/SSDT and SSIS are you using?

Comment: The standard way to load data into a Hive "external" table is to dump the data files directly into the appropriate HDFS directory -- last time I checked, SSIS basically was limited to CSV format and HDFS REST API.

Comment: I am using SSDT 2015 and the PackageFormatVersion is 8, targeting Sql Server 2017.